# WebView2 - This site is trying to open (application)

Tags: c#, vb.net, microsoft-edge, webview2

Using WebView2 browser when a user clicks a link that opens another program,  this prompt shows up every time.

Is there a way to suppress this in WebView2?

Comment: Have you took a look at [NewWindowRequested Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.818.41)? There may be other events as well that may be useful, check [them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.818.41) out.

Comment: Can you use the NavigationStarting event to cancel navigations to URIs that don't start with http/https?

Comment: I want them to always allow to view the link without the message prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [NavigationStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.navigationstarting?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.818.41) event to cancel navigations to URIs that start with the URI schemes you care about and then do whatever you like with that URI. For example, call ShellExecuteExW, or Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync with the URI so that the OS opens the URI.

As Yu Zhou notes this is dangerous if its arbitrary websites opening arbitrary applications as in the case of a web browser. If you're going to skip this security prompt you should ensure that you own the web content or trust the web content in the WebView2 to not be malicious. If you are showing arbitrary URIs or user submitted web content you should not skip the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that you want to bypass the prompt, but **it's by design and we can't change it**. It is designed for security. This prompt is the only thing standing between every arbitrary site on the Internet (loaded inside your browser’s sandbox) and a full-trust application on your computer (running outside of the browser’s sandbox).

The only thing we can do to reduce the pain is to check the "Always allow..." checkbox, so that the prompt won't show at the next time.